# etcd & kubernetes: No connection possible to etcd instance

Tags: kubernetes, etcd

currently I am following the k8s guide "from scratch" (found here: [LINK](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/scratch/), up to this point everything seems pretty clear, though I start without doing all that certificate stuff.

I started kubelet on master and added the etcd.manifest file [found here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.2/cluster/saltbase/salt/etcd/etcd.manifest)

Kubelet finds the manifest file and start two containers: One container running etcd and on "pause" handling the port mapping:  0.0.0.0:2379-2380->2379-2380/tcp.

Unfortunately, I cannot access etcd by doing a telnet IP_OF_SERVER:2379 oder 2380. 
Doing this on localhost, (telnet 127.0.0.1 2379) results in a connection that gets closed directly.

After a couple of seconds, kubeletes health check fails and the container gets shut down:

```
Jul 05 16:32:43 reactprd01.abc.com kubelet[18003]: I0705 16:32:43.834839   18003 manager.go:1751] pod "etcd-serverreact-reactprd01.abc.com_kube-system(b5a9f2d68d0d6160eed4a802d1afa5a7)" container "etcd-container" is unhealthy, it will be killed and re-created.
Jul 05 16:32:43 reactprd01.abc.com kubelet[18003]: I0705 16:32:43.835232   18003 manager.go:1371] Killing container "02df58ce685fd220cc19e6a38e8a5823de2699d869b5bb1789c50f1a6baa462b etcd-container kube-system/etcd-serverreact-reactprd01.abc.com" with 30 second grace period
```

Any idea on whats going on?
I replaced all placeholder (e.g. {{ port }} with data). I could not find anything on google as well.

Thanks for any advice :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the etcd.manifest file you linked to, etcd's stdout and stderr are redirected to a file mounted as a volume from `/var/log/etcd-serverreact.log`. It's possible that the file doesn't exist, or that your kernel doesn't support bind-mounting files (as opposed to directories) into Docker containers. And, for the long shot, maybe there's an error message in the file.